# What exactly is “quantification”?

Tags: writing, terminology, methodology

As I’m writing my final words within a research paper, I was curious regarding the term *quantification of results.*

Namely I’ve performed a correlation analysis in a quasi-experiment. The research is quantitative and purely related to software engineering.

My findings were that the two measured variables do correlate. Now, before I start getting into anything, what exactly specifies quantifying results of e.g. this correlation analysis?

Comment: I think you are confusing "quantification of results" with "quantitative analysis" and "quantitative variables".  Since you have quantitative variables and have performed quantitative analysis (correlation), your results are, by definition, quantified.  There is no separate "quantification of results" step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to report your findings:  Qualitatively and Quantitatively.

Qualitatively is just using words.  So you could say "we see good correlation between the datasets in the two experiments, but experiment A shows a slight bias at small time."

Quantitative analysis uses numbers.  You could say instead "Correlation analysis shows both datasets are correlated with p < 0.05.  Experiment A shows a bias of 0.1 at times less than one hour, and the correlation coefficient of both datasets using partial data fitting (I just made that up) is 0.13 with a t-critical value of 0.2.